# Getting the declared name of a variable passed into a method C#

Tags: c#, selenium, reflection

I've seen this discussed a few times before, and im not really sure if this is the best thing for me to be doing so any suggestions for improvement would be welcomed.

I'm trying to build some detailed logging for my Selenium tests.

I have a method call which is:

```
Admin_Login.Username.SetText("MyUsername");
```

Admin_Login is just a standard class. However "Username" is a variable passed into the "SetText" method which is shown below:

```
public static void SetText(this By identifier, string value)
{
    StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
    string methodName = stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name;
    string className = stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().DeclaringType.FullName;


    //I do some logging here for the manual testers so they can debug after a run
    TestDriver.ResultsLog.LogComment("Class: " + className);
    TestDriver.ResultsLog.LogComment("Calling Method: " + methodName);
    TestDriver.ResultsLog.LogComment("Calling Element: " + identifier.toString());

    IWebElement element = WebDriver.driver.FindElementSafe(identifier);
    ((IJavaScriptExecutor)WebDriver.driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].value = arguments[1]", element, value);
}
```

For reference, here is the Admin class:

```
public class Admin_Login
{
    public static By Username = By.Id("ctl00_MainContent_ctlLoginView_ctlLogin_UserName");
}
```

So I can log the class name and method name fine, but what I need to find out is the declared name of the "identifier" variable thats passed into the method.

So the value should be "Username" in this instance.

I've tried a couple of suggestions that yield the name of Identifier as "identifier" but that's really not what I want. I need to know which object the SetText method was called off, if that makes sense.

As I said maybe i'm not going about this the right way so any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: What use does this serve to "manual testers"? If they have access to a debugger and are expected to use one, they should be using it.

Comment: The manual testers are not coders so they will analyse a HTML results log that will tell them where the test failed and why. This is so that they can report this to the automation team or one of the developers on their team.
They aren't expected to use the debugger.
Debugging doesn't have to be using a physical debugger tool :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not believe I'm actually suggesting this because of how dirty this solution is... but, it is a solution... sooooo...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var foo = new Foo();
        var bar = foo;

        foo.Hit();
        bar.Hit();
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static void Hit(this Foo foo, [CallerMemberName] string name = null, [CallerFilePath] string path = null, [CallerLineNumber] int lineNumber = -1)
    {
        string callerVariableName;

        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            string csharpFile = reader.ReadToEnd();
            string[] lines = csharpFile.Split('\n');
            string callingLine = lines[lineNumber - 1];

            Match matchVariableName = Regex.Match(callingLine, @"([a-zA-Z]+[^\.]*)\.Hit\(\)");

            callerVariableName = matchVariableName.Groups[1].Value;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\n///////////////////////////////");
        Console.WriteLine("Caller method name:   {0}", name);
        Console.WriteLine("Caller variable name: {0}", callerVariableName);
        Console.WriteLine("File Path:            {0}", path);
        Console.WriteLine("Line number:          {0}", lineNumber);

    }
}

public class Foo
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks Aydin, i'll give it a try.
Sometimes dirty solutions are what unique problems require! :)

Comment: This seems to work for me. Im just wondering if this will work at runtime on a local machine running the unit test via a DLL since it wont have access to the C# file?